# API does not recognize ApiController

Tags: c#, rest, api, owin

I have a problem accessing my ApiController. When I make my API call, I get the following response:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/myapp/api/data/abc'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Data' that matches the request."
}
```

I want to create a OWIN web API on a TopShelf service where I can get some Data.
I'm new to this so I hope somebody can explain to me, what I've done wrong. It looks like it's something obvious I can't see.

Start:

```
var apiHostConfiguration = new Dictionary<string, WebApiHostConfig> {{"webApi", new WebApiHostConfig {Endpoint = "/myapp" ,RequiresOAuth = false}}};
// Start OWIN host 

const string baseAddress = "http://localhost";
foreach (var conf in apiHostConfiguration)
{
    var app = new WebApiApp();
    var opt = new StartOptions(baseAddress + conf.Value.Endpoint);
    OwinApps.Add(WebApp.Start(opt, app.Configuration));
}
```

ApiConfig:

```
class WebApiApp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: new {}
        );
        config.Formatters.Clear();
        config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
        config.EnableCors();
        config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
public class DataController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string Abc(string text)
    {
        var name = GetType().Name;
        return $"{name} pings back «{text}»";
    }
}
```

API call:

```
http://localhost/myapp/api/data/abc
```

Comment: Your route template does not include an optional parameter. It is also not very restful FWIW. Try `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{text?}", defaults: new {text = RouteParameter.Optional}` but consider that `routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{text?}",
            defaults: new {text = RouteParameter.Optional}` is likely preferable.

Comment: 'http://localhost/api/data/abc'

Comment: @AluanHaddad You solved my problem. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was like @AluanHaddad in a comment below my question said, that I did not define `string text` from my action into the route.

Comment:

```
Your route template does not include an optional parameter. 
It is also not very restful FWIW. 
Try 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{text?}", 
    defaults: new {text = RouteParameter.Optional} 
but consider that 
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{text?}", 
    defaults: new {text = RouteParameter.Optional} 
is likely preferable.
```

Thank you allot.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

> localhost

with your PRIVATE IP that assigned to your system on which you are running your web service/API

> i.e http://192.168.8.100

You can find your private ip

Type ipconfig /all at the command prompt: if you are on windows
Type ifconfig at the command prompt: if you are on mac